Was the deuterostome common ancestor a hemichordate, morphologically?
So it seems that the most accepted hypothesis now is that hemichordates are a sister group of echinoderms, not of chordates. Since acorn worms look to have a very basic, worm-y body-plan, how different would the deuterostome common ancestor have been from a hemichordate?
Additionally, since both hemichordates and chordates have gill slits and a post-anal tail, did the deuterostome common ancestor also have them?
